# How to convert NSURL to String

Tags: ios, string, swift, swift2, nsurl

I have a CameraVC class start with :

```
class CameraVC: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var image = UIImage()
var videoFilePath = NSURL()

...
```

I have this function :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let mediaType:String = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String

    print(mediaType)

    if mediaType == "public.image" {
        self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        if self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil)
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    } else if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        self.videoFilePath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
        print(self.videoFilePath)

        // THIS LINE IS NOT WORK ->
        let url = NSURL(string: self.videoFilePath)

        /*if self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera {
            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoFilePath) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoFilePath, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }*/
    } 
}
```

The line :

```
    let url = NSURL(string: self.videoFilePath)
```

is not working and i have a red alert with "Cannot convert value of type NSURL to expected argument type String.

The line :

```
print(self.videoFilePath)
```

write in console log :

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/071BCA9C-D246-4D14-9D56-34057A17079B/tmp/capture-T0x156501280.tmp.y4Ve7u/capturedvideo.MOV
```

Comment: You can access your URL path property to get its path: `if let filePath = (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL).path { print(filePath) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have `self.videoFilePath` as `NSURL`, you don't have to convert it to `String` and then `NSURL`

To keep the code safer:

```
if let path = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
    self.videoFilePath = path
    let url = path
    //Continue whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/absoluteString

Try `let url = NSURL(string: self.videoFilePath.absoluteString)`

Also you do realise that `self.videoFilePath` is already an NSURL...

Comment: This is pointless. Why not just `let url = self.videoFilePath`?

Comment: @rmaddy The question is specifically asking how to convert a NSURL into a string, which I have answered. I also pointed out that he can reuse the NSURL he has already fetched.

Comment: The OP is asking about a string because they are confused. There is no need at all to get a string involved since the need is to go from `NSURL` to `NSURL`.

Comment: There are still other answers the OP can look at. I am just answering the main question, "How to convert NSURL to String." As I said, I additionally specified that he is trying to convert a NSURL to an NSURL.

Answer (score 2):

You have a poorly named variable. self.videoFilePath isn't a path, it's a url. You're making it a URL here:
`self.videoFilePath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL`

Comment: Yeah I know, i change it when the converting working, thank for advice